# Store contents from an array into another array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So what that does is stores random values in the array elements from 31-58 and then total them up and average them and then I simply display them out.

My question is: **How can I take the days array which is used to give a day to every random number from 31-58 (28days in the month of february) and store it to a second array (weekday[]).So that at the very end of the program I can display the day name if I wanted.**

and My code looks like.(this is just a snipped)

```
double [] anArray = new double[366];//Keep track of all the days in the year
    String [] weekday = new String[366];//I hope to store the day names in this array
    String days[]={"monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday",
        "friday","saturday","sunday"};

//---each letter is 0 to start each new month at monday---
int a=0;int b=0;int c=0;int d=0;int e=0;int f=0;int g=0;int h=0;int i=0;
int j=0;int k=0;int l=0;//Days counter
//--These start at 1 to start each new month on the 1st
int jandays=1;int febdays=1;int mardays=1;int aprdays=1;int maydays=1;int jundays=1;
int juldays=1;int augdays=1;int septdays=1;int octdays=1;int novdays=1;int decdays=1;

            //Temperatures for February
for(int feb=31;feb <= 58;feb++){
    anArray[feb]=(int)(26 + Math.random() * (40-26+1));

    //System.out.println(days[b++ %7] + " january "+ (febdays++) +" at "+ anArray[feb]+" degrees"); // This is just testing to see if everything checks out.

    febtotal += anArray[feb];
}
febavg= febtotal/31;
System.out.printf("The Average temperature in February: "+"%.2f",febavg);
System.out.println("");
```

Hell what I'm asking for is actually kinda confusing me o.o.

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself handling lots of different `array` types, it's probably best to take a breath, and think with objects.

```
public class WeekDay {
    private int number;
    private String name;


    public WeekDay(int number, String name) {
         // Your constructor here.
    }

    /** GETTERS AND SETTERS **/
}
```

Then you create a `List` to contain them..

```
List<WeekDay> weekDays = new ArrayList<WeekDay>();
```

When the `WeekDay` Objects have been averaged, you can cycle through each one, and call `getName()` *(you'll need to add this)* to return the name of the day. This provides a much cleaner, more manageable and presentable code and it will help you conceptualise your goals a lot more efficiently. Honestly, OOP is awesome for complex situations.

**Edit**

The trick here is to map the `index` to the day name. Let's say you have an array like this..

```
 [0] = 0
 [1] = 0
 .
 .
 .
 [34] = 3
 [35] = 9
 .
 .
 .
 [62] = 7
 [63] = 0
```

Your numbers are between `34` and `62`. Those values need mapping to days, so lets start by making a method.

```
 public String[] mapDays(int[] dayNumbers, int startNumber, int endNumber) {
    // Your code in here.
 }
```

You pass in the array containing all of the numbers, and you pass in when the month's numbers start and end. Then, you're going to perform some checks.

```
 // First, you make a new array.
 String[] dayNames = new String[dayNumbers.length];

 for(int x = startNumber; x <= endNumber; x++) {
      // You now need to map the value of x, to the week day name.

 }
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to do methods or objects seeing I haven't gone that far in my programming class yet.  This assignment is based on arrays.  This is rather hard so I guess I have to just use arrays.  Any way I can do this with out objects?

Comment: Gonna be blunt with you bro. I haven't done methods or any of that.  The highest I've gotten too is arrays.  I don't think I can spend hours understanding those when I need to focus on arrays right now.

Comment: As you can see from my edit, all I have done is a few `if` statements, which I'm sure you *should* have covered before looking at `array`s.. but I'll simplify it for you.

Comment: I seriously appreciate your help though.  Not many people even want to do that.